# Avoid an incorrect request from view

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a xml file with a list like this

**view.xml**

```
<List
    id="myList"
    items="{
        path: '/myEntitySet'
    }">
    <items>
        <StandardListItem
            title="{myTitle}" />
    </items>
</List>
```

"myEntitySet" needs a dynamic filter parameter (myId) for a functioning response otherwise i'll receive an 404 error from backend.
So i use JavaScript to add a filter to my list.

**controller.js**

```
var oBinding = this.getView().byId("myList").getBinding("items");
var aFilter = [ new sap.ui.model.Filter("myId", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, myDynamicId ) ];

oBinding.filter({                      
            filters: aFilter
            });
```

Problem:
The "View-Request" fires miliseconds before the "controller-Request" and the request failed (404 Error).
I don't want to render the list by JS to avoid the request from the view.  Is there a way to prevent the request from view?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways you can do this.

The easiest would be to do the filtering directly in the XML, but I assume that your dynamic filtering parameter cannot be written at design-time, so this option is out.

You can do the binding only in the controller. Because you said you don't want to 'render' the list in JavaScript, you can use the following snippets.

View:

```xml
<List id="myList">
    <dependents>
        <StandardListItem id="myItem" title="{myTitle}" />
    </dependents>
</List>
```

Controller:

```
this.byId("myList").bindItems("/myEntitySet", {
   template: this.byId("myItem"),
   //optional:
   templateShareable: true
});
```

Another possibility is to use the deferred batch groups functionality of the OData model (v2). Basically you can group requests together in a single batch request by giving the batch request an `groupId`.

If you mark such a group as deferred, then the group (and its contained requests) are submitted when call the `submitChanges` method of the OData model. Check out the documentation for the [ODataListBinding](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataListBinding.html) and the [ODataModel](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.html#setDeferredGroups).

View:

```xml
<List id="myList" items="{
    path: '/myEntitySet', 
    parameters: {batchGroupId: 'myGroup'}
}">
    <StandardListItem title="{myTitle}" />
</List>
```

Controller:

```
//in onInit
this.getModel().getDeferredGroups(["myGroup"]);

//after you added the filter
this.getModel().submitChanges();
```

Comment: "Error: Missing template or factory function for aggregation items of Element..." for "dependents"-solution

`<List id="MasterList" mode="None" select="onListItemPressed"
    >
    <dependents>
     <CustomListItem type="Navigation" id="MasterListItem" press="onListItemPressed"
      iconInset="false">`

Comment: The error is not coming from the view (assuming that that's all that you wrote there), but from the place where you are binding the list. Make sure that you are passing the `template` accordingly (the error says that you are not passing a template there).

Comment: in "onAfterRendering" i call 
`oList.bindItems("/myEntitySet", {
         template: self.byId("MasterListItem"),
         filters: [new sap.ui.model.Filter({
                          and: true,
                          filters: aFilter
                      }, false)],
         //optional:
         templateShareable: true
      });`

I get the template with `self.byId("MasterListItem")`

BTW: There's no aggregation like dependents in [ListBase](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.ListBase/aggregations) Have you any further information about that?

Comment: Dependents is an aggregation inherited from [sap.ui.core.Element](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Element.html#getDependents). If the dependents was not found, you would get an error message saying something along the lines `Control sap.m.dependents not found.`. I guess you should check if the `self.byId("MasterListItem")` returns something.

Comment: `self.byId("MasterListItem")` returns `Element sap.m.CustomListItem#__xmlview1--MasterListItem`